# Is std::regex lib works for linux?

Tags: regex, linux, c++11

I am wondering if std::regex as described in the link: 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

Is cross-platformed and can work on linux machine as well as on Windows?

Comment: What you show is a standard library which should work the same everywhere

Comment: I added the C++11 tag, per the linked library documentation.

Comment: gcc added std:regex in version 4.9.something. If you have a later version than that, then yes.

Answer (score 2):

`std` stands for Standard. `std::regex` too is part of the C++ Standard Library. It's available in all modern compilers, regardless of OS or CPU. However, it was introduced in C++11 so it may not be available in old compilers.

Comment: My gcc version is 4.8.5-11 (Red Hat), and that std::regex lib doesn't seem to work on that version. Is there other similar lib for regular expression that I can use for gcc less then 4.9.x ?